# Determining if a method overrides another at runtime

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, overriding

I was wondering if there was any way to determine if a method represented by given `java.lang.Method` object overrides another methods represented by another `java.lang.Method` object?

I'm working on [Stronlgy typed javascript](http://st-js.sourceforge.net/), and I need to be able to be able to know if a method overrides another one in order to be able to rename both of them to a shorter name.

In this case, I am talking about the extended definition of overriding, as supported by the `@Override` annotation, which includes implementation of interface and abstract class methods.

I'd be happy with any solution involving either reflection directly, or using any library that already does this.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but as far as I know there's no built in way to do it. All you have to do is check the conditions for the definition of overriding in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8).

Comment: I know, but since this is far from trivial, especially when we are talking about generic methods, or methods that have arguments using the generic type parameter of the declaring class.

Comment: If you use the Override annotations on all overriding methods, you can just check for the presence of the annotation.

Comment: @jeff The Override annotation is a SOURCE annotation, meaning it is not present in the compiled file.

Comment: The `@Override` annotation has the `retention=source`, so it won't be present in compiled classes. On top of that, the program I'm writing is supposed to analyze code written by third parties, therefore, I do not have that kind of control on the classes.

Comment: oh, learned something new - sorry

Comment: @LordOfThePigs It is far from trivial, but I'm not sure if there's another way.

Comment: A related but distinct question: given a `Method`, can you easily find whether it is an override (and if so of what)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply cross-check method names and signatures.

```
public static boolean isOverriden(Method parent, Method toCheck) {
    if (parent.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(toCheck.getDeclaringClass())
            && parent.getName().equals(toCheck.getName())) {
         Class<?>[] params1 = parent.getParameterTypes();
         Class<?>[] params2 = toCheck.getParameterTypes();
         if (params1.length == params2.length) {
             for (int i = 0; i < params1.length; i++) {
                 if (!params1[i].equals(params2[i])) {
                     return false;
                 }
             }
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, since your goal is to rename methods, you might instead wish to use a bytecode analysis/manipulation library such as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), where you can perform the same tests as well as easily modify the methods' names if the method returns true.

Comment: Don't forget about the `return` type, `throws` declarations, or generic compatibility.

Comment: @Jeffrey Return type is checked, and `throws` declarations do not matter here, because a method is overriden if its name and signature are the same as that of a method in a parent class.  Generics are also irrelevant for this same reason.

Comment: Does return type really matter? I don't think they do, they are not part of the method signature. And then I disagree that generics are irrelevant. What if you have `class Parent<T>` with `void foo(T param)` and `class Child<String> extends Parent<T>` with `void foo(String param)`. Won't your implementation fail to recognize the overriding relationship?

Comment: Minor suggestion - Array.equals() could save some typing in that comparison loop.  e.g.  `return Arrays.equals(params1, params2);`

Comment: @Vulcan `throws` declarations do matter, the overriding method may not declare a checked exception in its `throws` that is not present in the overridden method's `throws`.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs Return type is indeed part of the method signature (i.e. the signature of my posted method is `Z(Ljava.lang.reflect.Method;Ljava.lang.reflect.Method;)`).  That example for generics will most likely need a case added to the posted method, good point.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs `return` types must be covariant.

Comment: @Jeffrey A class won't even compile if an overriding method declares a checked exception via `throws`, so that isn't a necessary check to be made.

Comment: Right, but if they aren't covariant the java compiler won't let the class compile anyway, so that's really not necessary, is it? Edit: beaten to it by a hair...

Comment: @LordOfThePigs Good point; that's in the same situation as `throws` actually, so you can remove return type checking.  Only name and parameter equality should be necessary for checking compiled code.

Comment: @Vulcan, the return type is not part of the method signature according to the [JLS §8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)

Comment: @Vulcan But as I said before, parameter equality is not that trivial when generics are involved.

Comment: @user949300 I won't include that, because extra checks for generics are necessary.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs My bad, you are correct.  I was thinking of the bytecode signature, which consists of return type and parameter types.

Comment: As an aside, I like questions like that, that spark a long thread of comments :-)

Comment: @LordOfThePigs You should be able to use `getDeclaringClass().getGenericSuperclass() / getGenericInterfaces()` to get the [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html)s for all of the super types. From there you can use `getActualTypeArguments()` and `getRawType().getTypeParameters()` to construct a mapping from `TypeVariable`s to `Type`s.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, hoping a better solution comes along at some point in the future... It's really a hole in the Java libraries, IMO.