# Is the JLS complete regaring method overriding and generics?

Tags: java, generics, jls

So, I was trying to write a method to answer one of my previous questions: [How can I find out if an arbitrary java.lang.Method overrides another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133817/) To do that, I was reading through the JLS, and there are some parts that seem to be missing in one case.

Imagine you have the following classes:

```
public class A<T> {
    public void foo(T param){};
}

public class B extends A<String> {
    public void foo(String param){};
}
```

In this case, it is quite obvious that `B.foo` overrides `A.foo`, however I don't understand how this case fits the specification.

Regarding method overriding, the [JLS §8.4.8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) states:

> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> 1. C is a subclass of A.
> 2. The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
> 3. Either:
>
>    - m2 is public, protected, or declared with default access in the same package as C,or
>    - m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2), such that m3 overrides m2.

Obviously points 1 and 3 are satisfied in our case. Let's look a bit deeper in the JLS what subsignature means. The [JLS §8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) says:

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types.
>
> Two method or constructor declarations M and N have the same argument types if all of the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. They have the same number of formal parameters (possibly zero)
> 2. They have the same number of type parameters (possibly zero)
> 3. Let A1, ..., An be the type parameters of M and let B1, ..., Bn be the type parameters of N. After renaming each occurrence of a Bi in N's type to Ai, the bounds of corresponding type variables are the same, and the formal parameter types of M and N are the same.

In our case, point 1 is clearly true (both have 1 argument).

Point 2 is a bit more muddy (and that's where I'm not sure what the spec means exactly): Neither of the methods declare their own type parameters, but `A.foo` uses `T` which is a type variable that paramterizes the class.

So my first question is: in this context, **do Type variables declared in the class count or not?**

Ok, now let's assume that `T` doesn't count and that therefore point 2 is false (I don't know how I could even apply point 3 in this case). Our two methods do not have the *same* signature, but that doesn't prevent `B.foo` from being a subsignature of `A.foo`.

A little further in [JLS §8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) it says:

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
> 1. m2 has the same signature as m1, or
> 2. the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.

We have already determined that point 1 is false.

The erasure signature of a method according to [JLS §4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) is `a signature consisting of the same name as s and the erasures of all the formal parameter types given in s`. So the erasure of A.foo is `foo(Object)` and the erasure of B.foo is `foo(String)`. These two are different signatures, therefore point 2 is also false, and B.foo is not a subsignature of A.foo, and therefore B.foo does not override A.foo.

Except it does...

**What am I missing? Is there some piece of the puzzle that I'm not seeing, or is the spec really not complete in this case?**

Comment: see Oracle's tutorial section on bridge methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do Type variables declared in the class count or not?

The elements in question are the methods, not the containing type declarations. So, no, they don't count.

> Ok, now let's assume that T doesn't count and that therefore point 2 is false

Why? They both have 0 type parameters, so it's true.

---

Step by step:

> - They have the same number of formal parameters (possibly zero)

Both methods have 1 formal parameter. Check.

> - They have the same number of type parameters (possibly zero)

Neither method declares a type parameter. Check.

> Let A1, ..., An be the type parameters of M and let B1, ..., Bn be the type parameters of N. After renaming each occurrence of a Bi in N's type to Ai, the bounds of corresponding type variables are the same, and the formal parameter types of M and N are the same.

Since neither method declares a type parameter there's nothing to rename and the formal parameter types are the same -- `T[T=String] = String`. Check.

⇒ `B.foo(String)` has the same signature as `A<String>.foo(String)`.
⇒ `B.foo(String)` is a subsignature of `A<String>.foo(String)`

Since `B` is a subclass of `A` and `A<String>.foo(String)` is public we can [conclude](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) `B.foo(String)` overrides `A<String>.foo(String)`.

Comment: The key step here being that `B` extends `A<String>` and not `A<T>`, and that therefore the signature of the method in the base class should be understood as `foo(String)` and not `foo(T)` or `foo(Object)`. I get it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must look at it this way:

The class `B` extends the type `A<String>`, which has a method `foo(String param)`.

`A<String>` is an *invocation* of the generic type `A<T>`. It is a type in its own right. This is implied by [JLS 4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5), which defines what a parameterized type is. `A<String>` is a parameterized type and is on equal footing with any other reference type. The fact that it is parameterized is not important when discussing the concept of the direct superclass.

Comment: Sure, I know how to instinctively interpret the case. But where in the Language specification does it formally explain that it works like that?

Comment: It is implied by [4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5), which defines what a parameterized type is. `A<String>` is a parameterized type and is on equal footing with any other reference type. The fact that it is parameterized is beside the point when disucssing the concept of the direct superclass.

Comment: So in my case, the correct thing to do would be to take `A.foo(T)`, rewrite it as `A.foo(String)` (since that's the instance of `A<T>` that we are talking about), and start following the specification for method overriding from that point? If that's the case and you could update your answer to reflect it, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) on generics:

> After type erasure, the method signatures do not not match. The Node method becomes setData(Object) and the MyNode method becomes setData(Integer). Therefore, the MyNode setData method does not override the Node setData method.
>
> To solve this problem and preserve the polymorphism of generic types after type erasure, a Java compiler generates a bridge method to ensure that subtyping works as expected.

So basically, compiler magic makes your compiled code work as expected, even with the JLS as it is. I'm not sure where this behavior is specified.

Comment: Well, the compiler makes some stuff so that the JVM can interpret it. So its consitent with the java bytecode specification. But how is that consistent with the java _language_ specification.

Comment: That's an answer to a completely different question ("How does a call to `A.foo(Ljava/lang/Object;)V` on an instance of `B` get dispatched to `B.foo(Ljava/lang/String;)V`?").

Comment: @BenSchulz Agreed. Bridge methods are an implementation detail of the compiler and are never mentioned in the Java _Language_ Specification.

Comment: JLS are more towards the run-time behavior of the code that you write. Any trickery (_Bridge methods in this particular case_) by which these specs are achieved should not be part of JLS. Tricks like these are employed for implementation of JLS so that a java source code remains as per JLS with same run-time behavior (_polymorphism in this case_).

Comment: And that's my point. The JLS alone doesn't cover the case I outlined in my question.