# Is there any algorithm to judge method overriding for Java at Runtime?

Tags: java, overriding

I am working on a fundmental programming project which is dealing with java class metadata (byte code and reflection) a lot. There is a very common case to identify:

- Does a method have an Annotation
- How do I determine whether or not two methods have the same annotation, does one of the methods override another method?

For the first question, imagine there are two classes: class T and class S as following:

```
public class T<O extends T<?>> {

    public void print(S o) {}
    @Transition
    public void print(O o) {}
}

public class S extends T<S> {

    @Override
    public void print(S o) {}
}
```

If the API wants to be smart and enable the API user to put @Transition on a super class or interface, then it will produce the same effect as putting @Transition on subclasses' overriding methods. Right now I am not sure if this is possible, how do I determine which methods S.print(S) overrides in class T?

For the 2nd question, the code goes as following:

```
public class T<O extends T<?>> {

    @Transition
    public void print(S o) {}
    @Transition(type=Redo.class)
    public void print(O o) {}
}

public class S extends T<S> {

    @Override
    @Transition(type=Redo.class)
    public void print(S o) {}
}
```

There is a constraint that Redo type @Transition method can be ONLY defined once through the class hierarchy. So in runtime while verifying this constraint, how can I determine that S.print(S) overrides T.print(S) or T.print(O), and that it will produce a different result? And the situation might be more ambiguous. Since it is more like jvm or the compiler's native feature, is there any algorithm available? Or is it possible to achieve this? Or should I maybe find some other directions?

Comment: Are you sure your second example compiles?

Comment: Yes, it compiles. You can try. At least in my Eclipse.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133817/determining-if-a-method-overrides-another-at-runtime .  You might consider modifying an existing Java compiler, or at least studying one to see how it makes method overriding decisions when checking `@Override`.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.reflect.Method has

```
public Class<?>[] getExceptionTypes()
public <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass)
public Annotation[] getDeclaredAnnotations()
```

Guess you can use them to get annotation and to get list of classes to the hierarhy root.

Comment: Thanks Bro. But I am not only asking for getAnnotation on a method of a subclass, but also it's interface's method and superclass's method, which had been overriden. The problem is i cannot find which method had been overriden, while Generic Type is involved, especially it is ambiguours sometime.

Answer (score 0):

If Method.getDeclaringClass() returns a different value from the class you got the Method from, it's an override or interface implementation, and you can tell which by looking at the declaring class.

Comment: Thanks bro, the access pattern may not same. I want to find all methods that had been override by a subclass method, and get all of the annotations on them. If I cannot get a wanted method, how can I use Method.getDeclaringClass() ?